# How to add a new property to an existing object dynamically in php?

Tags: php, loops, oop

I am new to php, T am trying to add a new property **onhold** to my object.

$designation is an object array coming from data base.

```
 $data = array(
        "page" => $this->page(),
        "requisitions" => \aljaber\requisition\requisition::find($this->registry, array()),
    );

    $designation = $data["requisitions"];


    foreach ($designation as $key => &$value) {
        $result = json_decode($value["Designation"], true);
        $hold = 0;
        foreach ($result as $v)
        {
            $hold = $hold + $v["onhold"];
        }
        $value[ 'onhold'] = $hold;
    }
    echo self::load_view("list", $data);
```

Any help appreciated.

[image: $value]

Comment: i tried the same way, but no luck..

Comment: $value is  just a ref used in the loop, $designation is the result coming from the data base. I updated my code to explain what I am doing.

Comment: Any chance you can show `var_dump ($value)`?

Comment: I added an image to give the details about $value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess what I was getting at was what is the Class Type for &$value? If it's pretty generic you might be able to get away with swapping it for a dynamic object.

Comment: So `$value` is an array? So `$value['onhold'] = $hold`?

Comment: yea, I'm going to go back to my original comment. If you accessed $value as an array to get `Designation` then you should be able to use array notation to add a property.

Comment: Thanks every one, I solved the problem by the changing the foreach loop in the following way.

`for ($i = 1; $i <=sizeof($data["requisitions"]); $i++)
        {
            $obj = $data["requisitions"][$i];
         $result = json_decode($obj['Designation'], true);
            $hold = 0;
            foreach ($result as $v)
            {
             $hold = $hold + $v["onhold"];
            }
            $data["requisitions"][$i]["onhold"] = $hold;
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$value` is not an object, is an array. This can be seen in the screenshot you are attaching (is better if you add the code instead images, but it's ok).

To solve this you have two options: change `(array)$value` with `(object)$value` or add a key to the array and then convert to object:

```
 $value['onhold'] = $hold;
 var_dump($value); // Array(1) { "onhold"=>"value" }

 $objValue = (object)$value; //convert an array to an object
 var_dump($objValue); // Object(1) { "onhold" => "value" }
```